# Custom paging for UIScrollView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I have a UIScrollView that scrolls horizontally with paging enabled. Is there any way to change the paging of the scrollview so that it snaps half way through the entire length of the scroll view. I've added pictures that show what i'm looking for.

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

[image: Page 3]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


let scrollView = UIScrollView()
scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width * 2, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

let view1 = UIView()
view1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.purple
scrollView.addSubview(view1)

let view2 = UIView()
view2.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
scrollView.addSubview(view2)

let view3 = UIView()
view3.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
view3.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
scrollView.addSubview(view3)

let view4 = UIView()
view4.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width + self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
view4.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
scrollView.addSubview(view4)

}
```

Comment: please elaborate more and show your code

Comment: I have a scrollview covering the entire screen and four views inside of the scrollview. Each of these four subviews have a width of half of the screen width. I would like this scroll view to snap to the next subview (which is half of the screen width). I'll attach a video along with my  code to show what I have already built.

Comment: Here is the video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6E9tiTyLokuRmVjelRmVWgzbHc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can set a delegate for the scrollView and implement one of the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(
    _ scrollView: UIScrollView,
    withVelocity velocity: CGPoint,
    targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>
)
```

You'll need to do a bit of custom logic when you receive this call.  Specifically you'll inspect the `targetContentOffset` as well as the `velocity` to see where the scrollView expects to stop and which direction the user is dragging, respectively.  Then you change the `targetContentOffset` to be the new location where it should actually stop.

In your case the new `targetContentOffset`'s `x`-value will be a multiple of the even pages.  Obviously if you have an odd number of pages you'll have to take the last page offset into account and do something a bit different.

You may also need to disable the default `UIScrollView` paging and handle all the paging yourself since your custom behavior conflicts with the default paging behavior.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this